# Fragment replace on Viewpager turns blank (Android)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

Whenever I try to replace my fragment inside recyclerAdapter, the fragment turns blank.

Here's how I've set up my code:

I have a viewpager with 4 fragments added to it. It's also aligned to a bottom navigation view, which means I can change fragments by sliding left and right, and I can also change fragments by using the navigation bar. So the bottom navigation bar is set up like this:

Fragment 1 | Fragment 2 | Fragment 3 | Fragment 4

The viewpager works perfectly, and it can change between these 4 fragments easily.

But then I also have a recyclerAdapter, which has set up cardviews inside Fragment 2 (RecyclerAdapter is in a seperate Java class, and NOT inside Fragment 2 java class).

So inside Fragment 2 i have 4 different fragments, which I'm going to call: Fragment 2.1, Fragment 2.2, Fragment 2.3 and Fragment 2.4. Whenever I click on the position of one of the cardviews, then I'm supposed to change fragment to either Fragment 2.1, Fragment 2.2, Fragment 2.3 or Fragment 2.4. Depending on which cardview I have clicked on.

These fragments 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 & 2.4 are not added to the viewpager.

But I have set up a code in recyclerAdapter to change fragments by begintransaction. Unfortunately I end up with a blank fragment, when I try to do this. My question is therefore, how can I change fragments which are added to viewpager? Do I have to add the fragments 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 & 2.4 to viewpager, or can I replace it with begin transaction somehow? Code is as follows:

RecyclerAdapter (Where I'm supposed to change fragment by clicking on position of cardview):

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from( viewGroup.getContext() ).inflate( R.layout.fragment_card_view_tabel, viewGroup, false );

    viewGroup.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    } );

    return new RecyclerViewHolder( view );
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder, int position) {

    recyclerViewHolder.mBeskrivelse.setText( OurData.beskrivelse[position] );
    recyclerViewHolder.mTitle.setText( OurData.title[position] );
    recyclerViewHolder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor( Color.parseColor( OurData.colors[position] ) );

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return OurData.title.length;
}


class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    public int nummer;
    private TextView mBeskrivelse;
    private TextView mTitle;
    private CardView cardView;
    private ViewPager mPager;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super( itemView );

        mPager = (ViewPager) itemView.findViewById( R.id.flMain );
        mBeskrivelse = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.item_beskrivelse );
        mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.item_title );
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById( R.id.card_view );

        itemView.setOnClickListener( this );

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        nummer = getAdapterPosition();

        if (nummer == 0) {

            //mPager.setCurrentItem(0);

            ((FragmentActivity) itemView.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace( R.id.flMain, new DataTabelFragment() ).addToBackStack( null ).commit();

        } else if (nummer == 1) {

            ((FragmentActivity) itemView.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace( R.id.flMain, new Sensor1Fragment() ).commit();

        } else if (nummer == 2) {

            ((FragmentActivity) itemView.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace( R.id.flMain, new Sensor2Fragment() ).commit();

        } else if (nummer == 3) {

            ((FragmentActivity) itemView.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace( R.id.flMain, new Sensor3Fragment() ).commit();

       }
        }

    }

}
```

ViewPagerAdapter (This is where my fragments from bottom navigation view is added):

```
public class ViewPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<Fragment> mFragmentListCardView = new ArrayList<>();


private final List<String> nameArray = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super( fm );
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String name) {

    mFragmentList.add( fragment );

    nameArray.add(name);

}

public void addFragmentCardView(Fragment fragment) {

    mFragmentListCardView.add( fragment );

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get( position );
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    //public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    //    return POSITION_NONE;
    //}

}
```

MainActivity (Where I add fragments to ViewPagerAdapter):

```
public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

    ViewPageAdapter adapter = new ViewPageAdapter( getSupportFragmentManager() );
    adapter.addFragment( new StartsideFragment(), "StartsideFragment" );
    adapter.addFragment( new CardViewTabelFragment(), "CardViewTabelFragment" );
    adapter.addFragment( new SensorOversigtFragment(), "SensorOversigtFragment" );
    adapter.addFragment( new KontaktFragment(), "KontaktFragment" );
    viewPager.setAdapter( adapter );

}

public void setViewPager(int fragmentNumber) {

    mPager.setCurrentItem( fragmentNumber );

}



public void enableViewPagerSwitch() {

    mPager.addOnPageChangeListener( new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            if (prevMenuItem != null) {
                prevMenuItem.setChecked( false );
            } else {
                mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem( 0 ).setChecked( false );
                navigationView.getMenu().getItem( 0 ).setChecked( false );

            }
            Log.d( "page", "onPageSelected: " + position );

            mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem( position ).setChecked( true );
            navigationView.getMenu().getItem( position ).setChecked( true );

            prevMenuItem = mBottomNav.getMenu().getItem( position );
            prevMenuItem = navigationView.getMenu().getItem( position );

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    } );

    setupViewPager( mPager );

}


public void bot_Navigation() {

    mBottomNav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById( R.id.nav_bot );

    botNavHelper.disableShiftMode( mBottomNav );

    mBottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener( new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.bot_startside:

                    setViewPager( 0 );

                    break;

                case R.id.bot_datatabel:

                    setViewPager( 1 );

                    break;

                case R.id.bot_sensorOversigt:

                    setViewPager( 2 );

                    break;

                case R.id.bot_kontakt:

                    setViewPager( 3 );

                    break;

                case R.id.bot_logUd:

                    setViewPager( 4 );
                    alertDialog();
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    } );

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    onCreate2();

    bot_Navigation();

}

protected void onCreate2() {
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById( R.id.toolbar );
    setSupportActionBar( toolbar );

    TextView mTitle = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById( R.id.toolbartitle );

    mTitle.setText( toolbar.getTitle() );

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled( false );


    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById( R.id.flMain );

    enableViewPagerSwitch();

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById( R.id.drawer_layout );
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close );
    drawer.addDrawerListener( toggle );
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById( R.id.nav_view );
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener( this );

    navigationView.setCheckedItem( R.id.nav_startside );

}
```

*** ADDED THE FRAGMENT 2 CODE HERE ***

public class CardViewTabelFragment extends Fragment {

```
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

public CardViewTabelFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.card_list, container, false );

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById( R.id.recycler_view );

    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter();

    recyclerView.setAdapter( adapter );

    final RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager( getActivity() );

    ((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).setOrientation( LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL );

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager( layoutManager ) ;

    return view;

    }

}
```

*** THANKS IN ADVANCE FOR THE HELP. I CAN ELABORATE IF NEEDED ***

Comment: You are using the fragment manager of the activity, instead use  `getChildFragmentManager()` in the fragment 2.

Comment: I have read about that several places, but I am not sure, where i have to change it to "getChildFragmentManager()"? In my recyclerAdapter? in that case I receive this message "Cannot resolve method" -> "((FragmentActivity) itemView.getContext()).getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace( R.id.flMain, new DataTabelFragment() ).addToBackStack( null ).commit();"

Comment: The definition of getChildFragmentManager() is:

Return a private FragmentManager for placing and managing Fragments inside of this Fragment.

Meanwhile the definition of getFragmentManager() (or in this case getSupportFragmentManager()) is:

Return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated with this fragment's activity.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't figure it out. Can you please elaborate? I understand the definition, but not how to implement it. I have attached the Fragment 2 in my question, which may make it easier. By the way , thanks for your time

Comment: Do you want me to change fragments, when I'm in fragment 2? In that case, thats what I'm trying inside the recyclerAdapter